# Python-Ficheros-Módulo Pickle

Tags: python, archivo, pickle

Tengo una consulta con respecto al Módulo Pickle... Estoy estudiando un ejemplo de como almacenar objetos en un fichero binario. Tengo el siguiente código:

```
# Creamos una clase de prueba
class Persona:

    def __init__(self,nombre):
        self.nombre = nombre

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre

# Creamos la lista con los objetos
nombres = ["Héctor","Mario","Marta"]
personas = []

for n in nombres:
    p = Persona(n)
    personas.append(p)

# Escribimos la lista en el fichero con pickle
import pickle
f = open('personas.pckl','wb')
pickle.dump(personas, f)
f.close()

# Leemos la lista del fichero con pickle
f = open('personas.pckl','rb')
personas = pickle.load(f)
f.close()

for p in personas:
    print(p)
```

Y lo que no estoy entendiendo es por qué en donde dice "#leemos la lista del fichero con pickle" iguala la lista "personas" que ya cargó con un "for" anteriormente, con "pickle.load(f)". En esa parte hago cortocircuito, se supone que personas es una lista, y que el fichero ya se encuentra escrito y ahora lo que quiero es leerlo, y no estoy entendiendo que está pasando jaja. De antemano muchas gracias!

Comment: Ase lo que tu dices, lee los datos y se lo asigna a la variable `personas`, obviamente esto sobrescribe los datos que tenia `personas` antes. Con esto no podrás saber que es lo que tenía antes la variable, solo cambia el nombre y listo (esto si quieres ver el valor de los datos de personas antes y después de leerlo)

Comment: Buenísimo!! Mil gracias!!

Comment: De nada, aquí estamos para ayudarnos :)